# VBA: SELECT statement run-time error

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub CmdPharmacy_Click()

Dim myM(11) As String

Set mydb = CurrentDb

If PMNM = "" Then
    PMNM = UCase(Left(cboMonth.Value, 3))
End If

sQ = "SELECT mN FROM PharDate WHERE mT = '" & PMNM & "';"
Set myrec = mydb.OpenRecordset(sQ, dbOpenDynaset)
myrec.MoveFirst
myC = myrec.Fields("mN")

For i = 0 To myC - 1
    myM(i) = "M" & i + 1
Next i

For i = myC To 11
    myM(i) = "NDATA"
Next i

'mydb.TableDefs.Delete ("PHAR_REPORT")

sQ = "SELECT HistoryData2.PR, HistoryData2.CC, " & _
       "HistoryData2." & myM(0) & " as U1, HistoryData2." & myM(1) & " as U2, HistoryData2." & myM(2) & " as U3, HistoryData2." & myM(3) & " as U4, " & _
       "HistoryData2." & myM(4) & " as U5, HistoryData2." & myM(5) & " as U6, HistoryData2." & myM(6) & " as U7, HistoryData2." & myM(7) & " as U8, " & _
       "HistoryData2." & myM(8) & " as U9, HistoryData2." & myM(9) & " as U10, HistoryData2." & myM(10) & " as U11, HistoryData2." & myM(11) & " as U12," & _
       "Revenue." & myM(0) & " as R1, Revenue." & myM(1) & " as R2, Revenue." & myM(2) & " as R3, Revenue." & myM(3) & " as R4, Revenue." & myM(4) & " as R5, " & _
       "Revenue." & myM(5) & " as R6, Revenue." & myM(6) & " as R7, Revenue." & myM(7) & " as R8, Revenue." & myM(8) & " as R9, Revenue." & myM(9) & " as R10, " & _
       "Revenue." & myM(10) & " as R11, Revenue." & myM(11) & " as R12, " & _
       "INTO PHAR_REPORT FROM HistoryData2, Revenue WHERE (((HistoryData2.PR) = Revenue.PR) And " & _
       "((Revenue.PR)>=76700000 And (Revenue.PR)<=76900000)) ORDER BY HistoryData2.PR;"
```

When I try and execute sQ, I receive the run-time error that.....
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
SELECT HistoryData2.PR, HistoryData2.CC, HistoryData2.M1 as U1, HistoryData2.M2 as U2, HistoryData2.M3 as U3, HistoryData2.M4 as U4, HistoryData2.M5 as U5, HistoryData2.M6 as U6, HistoryData2.M7 as U7, HistoryData2.M8 as U8, HistoryData2.NDATA as U9, HistoryData2.NDATA as U10, HistoryData2.NDATA as U11, HistoryData2.NDATA as U12 Revenue.M1 as R1, Revenue.M2 as R2, Revenue.M3 as R3, Revenue.M4 as R4, Revenue.M5 as R5, Revenue.M6 as R6, Revenue.M7 as R7, Revenue.M8 as R8, Revenue.NDATA as R9, Revenue.NDATA as R10, Revenue.NDATA as R11, Revenue.NDATA as R12 
   INTO PHAR_REPORT 
FROM HistoryData2, Revenue 
WHERE (((HistoryData2.PR) = Revenue.PR) And ((Revenue.PR)>=76700000 And (Revenue.PR)<=76900000)) 
ORDER BY HistoryData2.PR;
```

Comment: @HansUp....I used your suggestion and the query worked. But when I try and use the exact same SELECT statement I get this error message or too few parameters error message

Comment: How are you executing the query? Are you using querydef?

Answer (score 2):

You need to see the finished SQL statement you're attempting to execute.  Add a line before mydb.Execute like this:

```
Debug.Print sQ
mydb.Execute sQ
```

Debug.Print will print the statement in the Immediate Window.  (You can use CTRL+g to get there.)  Copy the statement, then open a new query, switch to SQL View and paste it in there, and try it.  Hopefully that effort will help you identify the problem.  If you can't resolve it, edit your question to include that statement so we can see it, too.

**Update**: The latest revision of your question includes a comma after the last field in your field list:

```
"Revenue." & myM(10) & " as R11, Revenue." & myM(11) & " as R12, " & _
```

Eliminate that comma after R12.

**Update2**: David Fenton spotted the missing comma in the SQL statement you included.  I would expect the missing comma to cause error 3075, "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ...".  However, your last report indicated the error message you're receiving is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".  I suspect we have been dealing with a moving target.  You've reported at least 3 different error messages.  And the SQL statement you posted was not consistent with the VBA code you showed us.

If your error message is still "Data type mismatch in criteria expression", try this query and show us what it gives you:

```
SELECT "HistoryData2" AS table_name, TypeName(PR) AS pr_data_type
FROM HistoryData2
UNION ALL
SELECT "Revenue" AS table_name, TypeName(PR) AS pr_data_type
FROM Revenue;
```

Comment: "too few parameters..." is what VBA says when you reference a field in a SQL query that does not exist.  In essence, VBA is expecting you to pass a parameter to replace the unknown value in the query.  With all of those dynamic field names one or more of them must be invalid...

Comment: @HansUp now I get the error message Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @Edmond Show us the actual SQL statement which produces that error.

Comment: @Edmond What are the data types of the PR fields in your HistoryData2 and Revenue tables?

Comment: @HansUp Number Data Type. Field Size is Double. And when you say, "show the actual SQL statement" what are you referring to?

Comment: @Edmond I meant show us the output from "Debug.Print sQ" --- the completed statement your VBA code builds, just before you ask CurrentDb to Execute it.

Comment: When I try an execute sQ I get an INVALID ARGUMENT error message

Comment: @Edmond Are you willing to email me a copy of your database?

Comment: I would but I think the database is too big to send via email

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL statement's SELECT clause you have this:

```
HistoryData2.NDATA as U12 Revenue.M1 as R1
```

It should be this:

```
HistoryData2.NDATA as U12, Revenue.M1 as R1
```

That is, a missing comma.

However, I see in the code that concatenates the string, the trailing comma is there. I can't explain the discrepancy, unless you've changed the code, or did not derive the SQL from the correct source.

Comment: When I try an execute sQ I get an INVALID ARGUMENT error message

Comment: After much back and forth, we still don't know exactly what SQL string you're attempting to execute, as your code did include the comma, but your report of the results did not. This cannot be true unless what you posted as the results of the concatenation came from somewhere else. Until we have the actual SQL string being executed, we can't even begin to look at it for problems.